# Prevent CollapsingToolbar continuing under status bar in Lollipop

Tags: android, android-toolbar, android-coordinatorlayout, android-appbarlayout

I have developed some custom behaviours for a `TextView` that changes position and size based on the height of the `AppBarLayout` inside a `CoordinatorLayout`. This is so that the title appears large and in the centre of the fully expanded `Toolbar` when open, but in the normal title position when the `ToolBar` is fully collapsed.

Take a look at the videos to see it on a [Lollipop](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BygzWY4QsrwEZmk2TGRoa1ZDeDA/view?usp=sharing) device (not working correctly) and a [JellyBean](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BygzWY4QsrwEa2RUU0hzclhGcFU/view?usp=sharing) device (working fine).

The issue occurs (I believe, based on my tests) on Lollipop devices only, and it seems to be linked to the fact that the status bar is an overlay on the Lollipop device, but not on the JellyBean one. This is reflected in my code as well, where to calculate the final `y` positions I need to do the following for the final position to be correct:

```
if (mFinalYPosition == 0) {
    mFinalYPosition = (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
        ? (((mContext.getResources().getDimensionPixelOffset(R.dimen.abc_action_bar_default_height_material)/2)) + getStatusBarHeight())
        : ((mContext.getResources().getDimensionPixelOffset(R.dimen.abc_action_bar_default_height_material)/2));
    }
```

The best solution for me would be if I could have Lollipop devices treat the status bar in the same as earlier Android versions, i.e. in a locked position, and not as an overlay.

How would I go about achieving this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to resolve this issue by removing all `android:fitsSystemWindows` elements from my `layout` `xml` file. In addition, it may be clear from the video I posted that some views disappeared during the animations on my Lollipop device then reappeared later. I was able to fix this by setting the `elevation` on certain `View`s to ensure they didn't vanish behind others during animation.